# How to fix "Anonymous type does not contain a definition for 'field'" error in linq join?

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have a dataset that has a datatable table1 that contains columns

*PlantId, PlantName, OrderWeek, supplierId, SupplierName, GroupId, GroupName, WeekDay, OrderCount, ReservedCount*

Then I have an enumerable GroupedByDate that has fields *OrderWeek, WeekDay, Supplier, SupplierId, PlantId, DeliveredCount*

That is created by

```
var GroupedByDate = from r in dsDta.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                    let eventTime = (DateTime)r["EntryTime"]
                    group r by new
                    {
                        WeekStart = new DateTime(eventTime.Year, eventTime.Month, eventTime.AddDays(-(int)(eventTime.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7).Day),
                        WeekDay = eventTime.DayOfWeek
                    } 
                    into g
                    select new
                    {
                        g.OrderWeek,
                        g.WeekDay,
                        g.Supplier,
                        g.SupplierID,
                        g.PlantId,
                        DeliveredCount = g.Count()
                    };
```

I would like to join these data using

```
var result = from T1 in table1.Rows.Cast<DataRow>() 
                         join T2 in GroupedByDate 
                         on new
                         {
                             PlantID = T1.Field<int>("PlantId"),
                             SupplierID = T1.Field<int>("SupplierId"),
                             OrderWeek = T1.Field<DateTime>("OrderWeek"),
                             WeekDay = T1.Field<int>("Weekday")

                         }
                         equals new
                         {
                             T2.PlantID,
                             T2.SupplierID,
                             T2.OrderWeek,
                             T2.WeekDay

                         } into JoinedData
                         from TotalData in JoinedData
                         select new
                         {
                             PlantId = TotalData.PlantID,
                             PlantName = T1.Field<string>("PlantName"),
                             OrderWeek = TotalData.OrderWeek,
                             SupplierId = TotalData.SupplierID,
                             SupplierName = T1.Field<string>("SupplierName"),
                             GroupId = T1.Field<int>("FuelGroupId"),
                             GroupName = T1.Field<string>("FuelGroupName"),
                             Weekday = TotalData.WeekDay,
                             OrderCount = T1.Field<int>("OrderCount"),
                             ReservedCount = T1.Field<int>("ReservedCount"),
                             DeliveredCount = TotalData.Field<int>("DeliveredCount")
                         };
```

Everyting goes fine except the last line

```
DeliveredCount = TotalData.Field<int>("DeliveredCount")
```

brings me an error:

Error   CS1929  '' does not contain a definition for 'Field' and the best extension method overload 'DataRowExtensions.Field(DataRow, string)' requires a receiver of type 'DataRow'.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that TotalData isn't of DataRow type and you cannot use .Field()
Try using

```
DeliveredCount = TotalData.DeliveredCount
```

Comment: Oh my. I thought intellisense didn't show "DeliveredCount" after TotalData. My mistake. This question could be removed...